# int are mutable in C. What is the purpose of using pointer to change the value of mutable object?

Tags: c, pointers, integer, dereference

Can anyone explain me the difference among these two?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {

int a = 10;
int *p = &a;
*p  = 11;  

}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
int a = 10;
a = 11;
}
```

Comment: No difference with respect to final value of  `a`. The first one is some artificial "obfuscation", perhaps for teaching pointers.

Comment: Unrelated: Note that `void main()` isn't a valid signature for `main`. It should be `int main()`

Comment: This is teaching pointers.  Functionally, a still equals 11.  The first code block sets p to the address of a.  Then using *p, you can manipulate a.  This technique becomes very important when dealing with structs and linked lists.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The presented two programs actually are equivalent except that in the first program the variable `a`  is changed through a pointer to it.

As it is written in the C Standard (6.2.5 Types, p.#20)

> ... A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a
> reference to an entity of the referenced type.

This property of pointers is used in C to implement the mechanism of passing objects by reference to functions.

Consider the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int x )
{
    x = 10;
}

void g( int *px )
{
    *px = 10;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 0;
    
    printf( "Before calling f x = %d\n", x );
    f( x );
    printf( "After  calling f x = %d\n", x );

    x = 0;
    
    printf( "\nBefore calling g x = %d\n", x );
    g( &x );
    printf( "After  calling g x = %d\n", x );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Before calling f x = 0
After  calling f x = 0

Before calling g x = 0
After  calling g x = 10
```

As you can see after calling the function `f` the value of the variable `x` declared in main was not changed. The problem is that the function deals with a copy of the value of the variable `x` declared in main. That is the function parameter is a local variable of the function that was initialized by the value of the variable `x` declared in main. Changing the local variable does not influence on the variable `x` declared in main.

But when the variable `x` is passed to the function `g` by reference through a pointer to it then the function is able to change the original variable `x` declared in main by means of dereferencing the passed pointer.

Also bear in mind that when you allocate a memory dynamically then allocated objects do not have names. You only have pointers to dynamically allocated objects. For example

```
int *px = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
```

So to change the allocated object you also need to dereference the pointer

```
*px = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case nothing, but suppose that you want to call a function, if want to edit the value of a FROM INSIDE that function, you'll need to use pointers.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void set_a(int *p, int val)
{
    *p = val;
}
int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    printf("a is: %d\n", a); // a is 2
    set_a(&a, 5);
    printf("a is: %d\n", a); // a is 5
}
```

that's just one use case. for instance, when using heap allocations, you'll need to use pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The two programs have the same observable effect.

> What is the purpose of using pointer to change the value of mutable object?

One good use is to be able to reuse logic. Write it once and use it many times.

Example:

```
void foo(int *X, int *Y) {
    /* some complex calculation */
    *X = *X + *Y + 1;
    *Y = *Y + *X + 2;
}
```

Now, you could use the function to do this "complex" calculation on different variables. You only need to write and test it properly once and can then reuse it many times.

```
int main() {
    int a = 10, b = 20, c = 30, d = 40;
    foo(&a, &b);
    foo(&c, &d);
    //...
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zEGTn64db)